# How do you solve for inverses when doing the Jacobian transformation method?

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, jacobian

Hopefully a very basic question. This is from a textbook exercise I'm doing to prepare for a class. Suppose I have two independent random variables, X and Y, and I am trying to find the joint distribution of U = X / Y and V = X + Y.

I know that the first step when using the Jacobian method would be to find the inverses of the above equations. I tried for 40 minutes to do this and couldn't figure it out. I looked at the solution and saw that the inverses are X = (U * V) / (1  + U) and Y = V / (1 + U). I can plug in and verify that these inverses are correct, but I have no idea how this was obtained. Is there some general method to find inverses like these quickly and efficiently? Am I supposed to use matrices or something? Currently my method is basically just plugging in with trial and error until I hopefully stumble upon the solution which hasn't been successful.

Comment: If U = X/Y, then UY=X. Then, V = UY + Y implying that V/(1+U) = Y. Hence, X = UV/(1+U). Basically, the "general method" should just involve basic algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Ok, thank you. that clears it up a bit for me. I think I just need practice doing these algebraic manipulations, it doesn't seem to come very naturally to me.

Comment: Indeed, problems like these often come to just pure practice (that's how I learned it as well). Good luck!